# How do I style a div but only if it has an H1 as its first child?

Tags: css

Is there a way that I can add `text-align:center` to all `div.wpb_wrapper` which have `h1` as the first child? One of the reasons I need this is that there are multiple `div.wpb_wrapper` that have the same parent, but not all have `<h1>` as the first child.

In the example below I only want to style the second div.

```
<div class="wpb_wrapper">
   <h2>Other text</h2>
   <p>Other text</p>   
</div>
<div class="wpb_wrapper">
   <h1>Text</h1>
   <h2>Other text</h2>
   <p>Other text</p>   
</div>
```

EDIT:  I can't apply `text-align center` to h1 because it is has `display: inline-block;` already applied. That's why I need to style the parent.

Comment: You cannot access the parent in CSS as of now. Sorry. :(

Comment: You cannot style a parent based on a condition of child with pure CSS. anyways in Jquery you can do it easily

Comment: @Quentin, that's bad. We know that there's no CSS parent selector, but the OP needs a working solution. This is not a dupe.

Comment: @Metzed, I am trying to support your case, someone voted me down and tells that this is not what you expect. Can you please clarify them that this is a better solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot access the parent in CSS as of now. But you can do something like this:

**Alternate Solution**

As there's no CSS Parent Selector, we can apply `text-align: center` for all the elements that are siblings and the `<h1>` itself this way:

```css
.wpb_wrapper > h1:first-child,
.wpb_wrapper > h1:first-child ~ * {
  text-align: center;
}
```

This will apply `text-align: center` to all the siblings. This way, the `<h2>` and `<p>` tags will be aligned center.

Let's try here:

```css
.wpb_wrapper > h1:first-child,
.wpb_wrapper > h1:first-child ~ * {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="wpb_wrapper">
   <h2>Other text</h2>
   <p>Other text</p>   
</div>
<div class="wpb_wrapper">
   <h1>Text</h1>
   <h2>Other text</h2>
   <p>Other text</p>   
</div>
```

According to the OP:

> I want to style the second div only. I do not want to center the text in the first `div`. I only want to center text in the `div` when it has an `H1` as the first child. And I can't apply `text-align` center to `h1` because it is has `display: inline-block;`.

So the only way would be:

```
.wpb_wrapper > h1:first-child ~ * {
  text-align: center;
}
```

Or using JavaScript or jQuery and using the `.closest()` this way:

```
$(".wbp-wrapper > h1:first-child").each(function() {
    $(this).closest(".wbp-wrapper").css("text-align", "center");
});
```

Comment: I seriously don't understand the reason for `-1`, when I can clearly demonstrate this solution works flawlessly.

Comment: See question clearly. `center` property should be applied to parent `div` not to siblings.

Comment: @niyasc What's the difference in this case? Don't think like a machine. We need solution, if not, an alternate. This is an alternate using pure CSS.

Comment: `is there a way that I can add text-align:center to all div.wpb_wrapper which have h1 as the first child?`. That means, everything inside div should be centre aligned if there is an `h1` tag as first child.

Comment: Good solution. Consider centering the h1 also. `.wpb_wrapper > h1:first-child ~ *, wpb_wrapper > h1 {text-align: center;}`

Comment: @PraveenKumar may be you can write a bolded text saying "Alternate solution" So that people dont bounce back with -1's

Comment: I want to style the second div only. I do not want to center the text in the first div. I only want to center text in the div when it has an `H1` as the first child. And I can't apply text-align center to `h1` because it is has `    display: inline-block;`

Comment: @Metzed Then see the first solution. Lemme add it for you.

Comment: @Metzed Pure CSS might be possible if you are more clear. But I have also added the jQuery way too.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you can't do that with CSS only.

If you are already using jQuery you could do this:

Javascript:

```
$('.wbp-wrapper > h1:first-child').each(function(){
    $(this).closest('.wbp-wrapper').addClass('centered');
});
```

CSS:

```
.centered {
    text-align: center;
}
```